# Python/Pandas: Using built-in functions as arguments in user-defined function

Tags: python, pandas, function

Very simple query but can't seem to find appropriate answer. I want to pass the Pandas method for e.g. .sum() as an input to my function.

```
def something(dataframe,col_name,func):
    return dataframe.col_name.func

something(df,'a',sum())
```

TypeError: sum expected at least 1 arguments, got 0.

Python confuses it with inbuilt function sum()

Comment: I'd just go with `return dataframe.groupby(col_name).agg(method1)`.

Comment: Please do not change your question after you have received 3 answers. If you have a new question, please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) so it can be answered separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You an use `operator.methodcaller` for this:

```
from operator import methodcaller

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(11)})

def foo(df, col, method):
    return methodcaller(method)(df[col])

res_sum = foo(df, 'a', 'sum')   # 55
res_avg = foo(df, 'a', 'mean')  # 5.0
```

The reason for your error is you are trying to pass the result of a called function with no arguments, one that happens to *require* arguments to work.

The benefit of passing strings is you rely on tried-and-tested methods built into the Pandas framework, e.g. [`pd.Series.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html), [`pd.Series.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mean.html), etc. While you can attempt to use Python built-ins and NumPy functions directly with Pandas series, you may find discrepancies versus what you might expect. Stick with documented Pandas methods where possible.

Comment: Works as intended. Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

Do not recommend acquiring functions by this method in a general case, but here is a solution without any additional imports.
Python has a `getattr` builtin function which "[r]eturn the value of the named attribute of object." Its usage is `getattr(object, name[, default])`. So you need to rewrite your function as the following.

```
def something(dataframe,col_name,func):
    return getattr(dataframe[col_name], func)

something(df,'a',"sum")
```

If you want to get the result of the function call sum, replace the function definition with `return getattr(dataframe.col_name, func)()`.